# Can you pre-configure country specific landing pages for certain targets?

Tags: javascript

I have an application with 3 different country specific landing pages, Germany, Switzerland & Austria. I also have clients from each of these countries, I know that I can use a simple GeoLocation API to gather my users location once they come to my site. But is there a way to preconfigure this so that's it a preset redirection aka that they don't have to give permission for me to receive their location? As an example.

- German Company will always be redirected to mysite.de,
- Swiss Company to mysite.ch
- Austrian Company to mysite.at

Comment: The short answer: "*it is illegal in EU to do it without consent*". Whether we're talking about location data from the device or about the user's IP address. IP addresses are considered personal data under EU law, because there are cases where a person can be identified by their IP and you can't separate them from the cases where the IP is not sufficient to identify a person.

Comment: The proper way to do it is to give the users the option. Let them know you have three websites and let them choose which one they want to visit. I might be currently in Austria but I might own a company in Germany and perhaps, by your own logic, I should be using the version aimed at Germany.

Comment: @tao interesting point re: EU privacy law, thanks for the clarification. Seems simplest is best in this case!